# Update a specific JPanel in a GridLayout of panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a `GridLayout` that contains 3 `JPanel` components.  I want to update **only** the second panel.

My problem is when I call the `jpanel2.repaint()`, there is no change because the `paintComponent` method does not be called.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: What Andrew said! Add the minimal amount of code to explain your issue.